# NCurses & Ubuntu terminal: Colors change when switching out of terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ncurses

When I switch out of my terminal (Ubuntu terminal) and back in, the colors of my program have changed. They don't change randomly, but to specific colors.

My setColor function, which returns an unsigned int ...

```
unsigned int Console::setColor(float r, float g, float b, float r2, float g2, float b2) {

    bool bkgd = true;
    if (r2 == -1.f || g2 == -1.f || b2 == -1.f) {
        bkgd = false;
    }

    clamp(r);
    clamp(g);
    clamp(b);
    clamp(r2);
    clamp(g2);
    clamp(b2);

    init_color(instance().colorNum * 2, static_cast<int>(r * 1000.f), static_cast<int>(g * 1000.f), static_cast<int>(b * 1000.f));
    init_color(instance().colorNum * 2 + 1, static_cast<int>(r2 * 1000.f), static_cast<int>(g2 * 1000.f), static_cast<int>(b2 * 1000.f));
    if(bkgd) {
        init_pair(instance().colorNum, instance().colorNum * 2, instance().colorNum * 2 + 1);
    } else {
        init_pair(instance().colorNum, instance().colorNum * 2, -1);
    }

    return ++instance().colorNum - 1;

}
```

... which I can use in this function to activate the color:

```
void Console::useColor(unsigned int pair) {

    wattron(win(), COLOR_PAIR(pair));

}
```

EDIT: Looks like it has something to do with the Ubuntu terminal. With xterm, it works. Also, the color values do not change, so maybe it has something to do with the purple color of the Ubuntu terminal?